# systemd Failed to start Store a System Token in an EFI Variable

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, uefi

A few weeks ago I started seeing this error in the journal after each boot. I believe it is related to a recent systemd update.

```
systemd[1]: Failed to start Store a System Token in an EFI Variable.
```

My system is:

```
5.3.1-arch1-1-ARCH

systemd 243 (243.51-1-arch)
+PAM +AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

Below is of the few things I found when researching the topic:

Failed to start Store a SystemToken in an EFI Variable · Issue #13603 · systemd/systemd · GitHub https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13603

There are two interesting comments at that link:

```
Message disappears after rebooting the newly installed OS.
```

That's not the case for me. I get the message on each reboot.

```
Suspect the EFI variable's name changed?
```

I do not believe it is that simple.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: I started seeing this about ten days ago on an 6.0.1-arch2-1. Any explanation on your side ? Tx